# Adding flags into tables dynamically

Tags: html, css, thymeleaf, flags, country

I was wondering if it is possible to add flags to the table dynamically. The countries listed below are just for examples but I want them to come out of a list and it should add the country flags dynamically next to a 3 char country code.

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Flag</th>
<th>Country</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>USA</td>
</tr>
<tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>GER</td>
</tr>
<tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>CHI</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

If it is possible, can someone help me, point me in a direction from which I can find a solution to this?

Comment: just call the flags the same as your 3 char country code and then you can just use the same thing you use to print out the country name as to change the src of the image

Comment: Oh, great idea, thank you!